# How to convert XML data from a String?

Tags: android, xml

Does anyone knows how to convert XML from a String? I have been seeing conversion from XML to String values, but not String to XML. I have a String that contains the XML content, but when I use the `parse()` method, it fails.

Here is the example:

```
 String content = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
Therefore content now contains:    
    content = "<MGMT>" +
        "<NET>" +
            "<HEAD>" +
                "<ClientID>99999999</ClientID>" +
                "<ServerID>WEB_01</ServerID>" +
                "<Rsp>00</Rsp>" +
                "<Auth></Auth>" +
            "</HEAD>" +
            "<STAT>" +
                "<IP>192.168.5.158</IP>" +
                "<Status>OK, Success!</Status>" + 
        "</NET>" +
    "</MGMT>";
```

Help please? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to create some sort of Java `XML` object that would represent the xml contained in the string? It's not super clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: The `XML` content is stored on a string variable. I want to parse that string storing the `XML` into values that I can use. In the example above. What I want to use are `<Status> Ok, Success!</Status>`, etc. But since its a string value, can I parse that? I've tried a `XMLReader.parse(content)` and it failed. I believe I may have done some steps wrongly, but I can't figure out which.

Answer (score 0):

Does your "content" follow the XML format? You can add a header in front of your "content",like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

I think you can first save your "content" to a file, and then parse the file. This can help you verify your XML format.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, it does have that. I didn't put it down here. How do I create a temp file to store it into? Then afterwards, parse it?

Comment: Your "content" is illegal as the other answer said. I think that is the problem. By the way, there should be a lot of XML parsers can parse a string as XML. [Here](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/) is a link that can help you validate your XML string.

Comment: Sorry! It doesn't have that UTF-8!! This is the format. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Your sample content is missing a closing STAT tag.

Once I added that, I was able to parse the string using LINQ to XML:

```
        string sContent =
        sContent = "<MGMT>" +
    "<NET>" +
        "<HEAD>" +
            "<ClientID>99999999</ClientID>" +
            "<ServerID>WEB_01</ServerID>" +
            "<Rsp>00</Rsp>" +
            "<Auth></Auth>" +
        "</HEAD>" +
        "<STAT>" +
            "<IP>192.168.5.158</IP>" +
            "<Status>OK, Success!</Status>" + 
        "</STAT>" +
    "</NET>" +
"</MGMT>";


        XElement element = XElement.Parse(sContent);

        string sStatus = element.Descendants("Status").First().Value;
```

I don't know if LINQ to XML is available when programming for the Android, but hopefully the identification of the missing tag will solve your basic problem.

Comment: Is the XElement an XML Parser?

Comment: It sounded as if you already had access to some parsing functionality when you referred to XmlReader in your initial post.  Have you tried using that with the revised content?